How can I store binary numbers in pandas?
I'm dealing with a large data set and I have a column that is treat as an object



Genotype
Iteration




10010110011011101101011000010011111011111000000111001001101111111101101111001011
0


00011100001011010000000110010010100101101011001010101110110111000101000110000000
0


00100100100100101000100101100110100101110000100111000000011001011001101111000011
0


10001010101100000101110001011111000110101100101010111100110011011101010011111110
0


11010101010010001110100110110001001010101001111000111011110110101101010100011110
0



This column is Genotype. Pandas right now is treating this column as an object and I don't know if there is any data type that allows me to treat it as a binary number (I guess that it's going to be cheaper??).
What interest me of this colum is the number of 1's that appear in each row so something like this I don't think that is going to work
df["Genotype"] = [int(x,2) for x in df["Genotype"]]


Can you clarify how you get the input? If this really a binary object (in which case you should be able to convert it directly to integer), or a string?

@mozway the input (I suppose you refer to the data source) is generated by another program (in C++) and in that program they are treated as strings

OK, then counting the '1''s might be the most straightforward. Maybe worth timing my two approaches with your real dataset though.

The integer + bin_count approch seems faster on large datasets (with strings as input)

You could use bit_count:
df['Genotype'] = [int(x,2).bit_count() for x in df['Genotype']]

Or, if a string, str.count:
df['Genotype'] = df['Genotype'].str.count('1')

Output:
   Genotype  Iteration
0        48          0
1        33          0
2        34          0
3        44          0
4        43          0

timings
On 500k rows:
# df['Genotype'] = [int(x,2).bit_count() for x in df['Genotype']]
259 ms ± 24.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# df['Genotype'] = df['Genotype'].str.count('1')
619 ms ± 18.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


genotype is not typically a binary number but rather a binary sequence. Meaning that you might not need to convert it to a number later. So the best data type option for that is object if you are using pandas and stringor 'U' (Unicode string) if you prefer to use numpy.
These data types ensure that the binary sequences are stored exactly as they are, without any truncation or conversion to numeric types that may lead to precision loss or overflow issues.
